Many To Many Product and Categories
so i have a many to many relationship data about categories and product
here the table
-- public.product definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.product;

CREATE TABLE public.product (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NULL,
    stock int4 NULL,
    price float8 NULL,
    capital float8 NOT NULL,
    picture text NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NULL,
    deleted_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- public.product_category definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.product_category;

CREATE TABLE public.product_category (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    product_id uuid NOT NULL,
    category_id uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_category_category FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES public.category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_category_product FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES public.product(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE public.category (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uni_category_name UNIQUE (name)
);

ok while i was making the api for getProductBynameAndCategories ( i can search by the name and can select many categories to get Products that i want ) i found the query thats look like this but the result is not what i wanted
SELECT product.name
  FROM product_category
  JOIN product ON product_category.product_id = product.id
  JOIN category ON product_category.category_id = category.id 

Result
so the result that i have is duplicate , so my question is how do i group the duplicate record with the category name ? and my purpose data was look like this :
Purpose
i Hope my question is clear and understandable that people able to reach my problem

Read an intrudoction on aggregates and the documentation for string_agg()

Pllease review [mre]  and add example data, ideally as executable SQL. Use inline text for information that is textual in nature: don't use images or links to images for such items (please address the "result" and "purpose" links accordingly). While it won't fix your query problem, there should be a unique index on product_category(product_id, category_id) to preclude redundant associations.
